# Problems running rethinkdb-dump from cron

Tags: python, bash, cron, rethinkdb

I'm trying to setup regular backups of rethinkdb, but keep running into issues. How do you setup rethinkdb-dump to run from cron?

Here is my script:

```
$ cat backup.sh 
#!/bin/bash
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")

/usr/bin/rethinkdb dump -e my_db -f /root/db_backup/$NOW.tar.gz
```

The script runs just fine when I run it manually. However, when try and run it from cron it doesn't work and I get the following at `stderr`:

```
Error when launching 'rethinkdb-dump': No such file or directory
The rethinkdb-dump command depends on the RethinkDB Python driver, which must be installed.
If the Python driver is already installed, make sure that the PATH environment variable
includes the location of the backup scripts, and that the current user has permission to
access and run the scripts.
Instructions for installing the RethinkDB Python driver are available here:
http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install-drivers/python/
```

It appears to be a Python environment issue, but I cannot figure out how to make it happy... thoughts? Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run it from that backup.sh script, it maybe run without correct PATH setup and cannot found the PATH of `rethinkdb-dump`.

First, let find out where is `rethinkdb-dump`

```
which rethinkdb-dump
(on my pc, I guess it's very different on your pc)
/usr/local/bin/rethinkdb-dump
```

Now, try to append the PATH to your script `backup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/folder/contain-rethinkdb-dump"
# The rest of your script normally
```

So take my example, I will put it like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

I think your `rethinkdb-dump` live outside normal `bin` folder (/usr/bin, /usr/local/bin etc)

Answer (score 0):

The python installer for windows installs scripts and packages in subfolders here:

`$env:APPDATA\Python\Python37` for **powershell**

`%APPDATA%\Python\Python37` for **cmd**

`cd` this directory to see **/Scripts** and **/site-packages** (*pip packages*)